# jQuery: Why doesn't this animate step function work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a method as suggested in [this Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3216230/jquery-recreate-slidedown-effect-using-the-animation-function), to recreate the jQuery `slideDown` function using `animate`, so that I can use the `step` property.

However, I can't get the step property to work. Here is my code:

```
    infoClone.animate({
        "height": "show",
        "marginTop": "show",
        "marginBottom": "show",
        "paddingTop": "show",
        "paddingBottom": "show",

        step : function() {
            console.log('Step!');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
infoClone.animate({
        "height": "show",
        "marginTop": "show",
        "marginBottom": "show",
        "paddingTop": "show",
        "paddingBottom": "show"
},
{
  step : function() {
            console.log('Step!');
        }
});
```

Comment: I used this answer as the other one had a mistake in it, it was missing a `{` before the `step`.

Comment: Perfect..! this works fine for me! Accept this answer if you have solved your problem

Answer (score 5):

You should change it to

```
infoClone.animate({
    "height": "show",
    "marginTop": "show",
    "marginBottom": "show",
    "paddingTop": "show",
    "paddingBottom": "show"
    }, {
    step : function() {
        console.log('Step!');
    }
});
```