# Animate content div 'height' to 'Auto' onclick - jQuery

Tags: jquery-animate, jquery

I have a content div that I want to be set to specific height (50px) then onclick change to 'auto' -
Can I make this work with jQuery? I have it in YUI see code below

```
 function toggleContent(p, showFull) {
    if (showFull) {
        YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(p, 'height', 'auto');
        p.setAttribute('onclick', "toggleContent(this, false);")
    } else {
        YAHOO.util.Dom.setStyle(p, 'height', '50px');
        p.setAttribute('onclick', "toggleContent(this, true);")
    }
    }
```

[Here is an example of I want (YUI)](http://jsfiddle.net/XUSdC/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003220/javascript-jquery-animate-to-auto-height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's that code updated to use jQuery:

```
function toggleContent(p, showFull) {
    if (showFull) {
        $(p).height('auto');
        p.setAttribute('onclick', "toggleContent(this, false);")
    } else {
        $(p).height('50px');
        p.setAttribute('onclick', "toggleContent(this, true);")
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ryanbrill/XUSdC/1/