# jQuery animate on property change

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

I have I `div` or some other element which I load content into with:

```
$('#my_div').load('ajax.php',function(){
    //Do random stuff.
}
```

However the height of the `div` will then change, causing the page to jump up and down, looking ugly.

Is there a way for it to animate the height when the new content is loaded or changed? I know one can do this with `FluidMoveBehavior` in C#.

How can I achieve the same effect with Javascript/jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's some Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F8ESC/)

When you want to create a height or width animation with jQuery you have to set a number indicating the desired size. I assume that you use height: auto in this case so you have to find a little workarround.

1. Get the height:

   ```
   var autoHeight = $("#content").height("auto").height();
   ```
2. Animate to `autoHeight`:

   ```
   $("#content").animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000);
   ```

And together:

```
   var currentHeight = $("#content").height();
   var autoHeight = $("#content").height("auto").height();
   $("#content").height(currentHeight);
   $("#content").animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000);
```

[Stolen from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003220/javascript-jquery-animate-to-auto-height)

Answer (score 0):

What I do is the opposite.  I animate the page to scroll to the top if not already BEFORE I call the load.

So that the top of any new dynamic content is always in view.

I know this isn't the answer you were looking for, but I've found it works best.

Answer (score 0):

You could hide `#my_div` before the `load()`, and then `slideDown()` in the complete function:

```
$('#my_div').hide().load('ajax.php', function() {
  $(this).slideDown();
});
```

Or, create a temporary element, hide it, append it, use its height to animate `#my_div` once the load is complete, and then remove it.

```
$('<span/>').hide().appendTo('body').load('ajax.php', function(text) {
  $('#my_div').animate({ height: $(this).height() }, '800').html(text);
  $(this).remove();
});
```