# Animate the change of height in a div on click of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have searched this all over Stack Overflow, found many answers, but none work with what I am specifically going for... basically I have no idea why this code does not work someone please help! Any input much appreciated, thanks!

Here is the HTML with the `div` to click with an `id` of `elementTop` and the `div` to be shown with animated height is `elementBottom`

```
<div id="elementTop" onclick="toggle_visibility('elementBottom');" >
    <img id="thumb" src="images/davey1.png" />
    <a>davey blair</a>
</div>

<div id="elementBottom">
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">age: </span>29</p>
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">hometown: </span>Charleston,SC</p>
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">regular or goofy: </span>Regular</p>                                                   
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">years shredding: </span>lifetime</p>
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">other sponsors: </span>naish, chucktown</p>
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">favorite trick: </span>switch mobe</p>
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">favorite place to shred: </span>with my homies</p>
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">music preference: </span>all music</p>
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">paper or plastic: </span>hands</p>
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">cat or dog: </span>dogs</p>
    <p><span style="font-weight: bold;">other hobbies: </span>living life. work to live never live to work, live life.</p>
</div>
```

And here is the JavaScript/jQuery I am using and the JavaScript lines I commented out work, however the jQuery that is not commented does not work.

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
  var e = document.getElementById(id);
  if(e.style.height == 'auto') {
    // e.style.height = '0px';
    $('#' + e).animate({height:'0px'});
  } else {
    // e.style.height = 'auto';
    $('#' + e).animate({height:'auto'});
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot animate to "auto"

Comment: tried animating to 500px... still did not work :(

Comment: Did you import the jQuery library? `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003220/javascript-jquery-animate-to-auto-height) may be useful

Comment: yes i did, like this {<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works, but you can never animated it back because you can't click on the element when it's `0px` high:

http://jsfiddle.net/neuroflux/UYZY2/23/

SNIP!

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
    $(id).stop().animate({height:'toggle'}, 500);
}

$('.clicker').on('click', function() {
   toggle_visibility('#' + $(this).attr('name'));
});
```

Comment: I like that a lot! and that is awesome it works I will try to use your ideas in my problem, but specifically what I am going for is for the user to click the div elementTop and have the elementBottom toggle hidden and shown by animating height

Comment: You could also change the height property to `toggle` instead of pixels. Shortens the code: http://jsfiddle.net/876R9/

Comment: Updated again with @Novocaine88 suggestion ;)

Comment: Cheers @swiper192! Note that I changed my JSFiddle to include `THE OLLIE` ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's a little odd that you're using jQuery and sometimes not. Use

```
var e = $('#' + id);
```

to get the Dom element you want to manipulate. Then you can just do

```
e.animate();
```