# How to change css property to auto, slowly with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have an element set as `position:fixed`, and `bottom: auto;` and at some point I do `.animate({bottom : '10%'});` it slides smoothly, and then I want to set it back to auto.

If I do `.css('bottom','auto');` it slides, but not slowly. So it goes to original position, instantly.

I cannot use `.animate();` so how can I do this?

one way could be using `.toggleClass();` , but isn't there a way without changing its class ?

I also tried to put a long `-webkit-transition` time, but it still moves to original position instantly.

And another solution could be to save the initial position in a variable and put it back there, but it does not work for me, because the initial position may, or maynot change in this function.

Comment: Can you add jsFiddle please?

Comment: This may be relevant to your needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003220/javascript-jquery-animate-to-auto-height

Comment: you mean to say with animation ..

Answer (score 3):

You can't slowly set something to auto in CSS because once it becomes auto, computations happen to actually assign auto to a value.  Since you're doing this in JS anyway, can't you do the computations and set the bottom value to that?

Answer (score 1):

Like this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/a8tQ2/

```
$('#scr').animate({
    bottom: '10%'
}, 1000, function() {
 $(this).css('bottom', 'auto');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this link http://api.jquery.com/animate/

```
 $('#uiAdminPanelMenu li a').hover( function(){
 $(this).animate({'background-color': '#D3E1FA'}, 'slow');
 },
 function(){
 $(this).animate({'background-color': '#F4F4F4'}, 'slow');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in CSS 3 using the transitions support: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/

For example:

```
div
{
 transition: width 1s linear 2s;
 /* Safari */
 -webkit-transition:width 1s linear 2s;
}
```

Comment: I also tried that. But maybe this way: can I do translate(0 , **to** a certain position); ?