# Hide a div at specfic height while using slidetoggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have three divs and i am trying to show/hide div2 when we click on any div. So far i have succeeded in it but now i want to implement some animation while show.hide the div.

I tried a lot and read many solution but due to i am new to jQuery i cant do it. Here is my code that i tried before animation

http://jsfiddle.net/9Lw6T/119/

```
$(".more , .expander,.headingopen").click(function() {
var expanderDiv = $(this).parents(".content_item").find(".textContent");

if ($(expanderDiv).length > 0 && $(expanderDiv).hasClass("expander") ) {
    $(expanderDiv).removeClass("expander");
    var MoreDiv = $(this).parents(".content_item").find(".more");
    $(MoreDiv).html("Mindre");
}
else {
    console.log("addclass");
     $(expanderDiv).addClass("expander new");
    var MoreDiv = $(this).parents(".content_item").find(".more");
    $(MoreDiv).html("More");
}
});

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery(".more , .expander,.headingopen").click(function() {
            jQuery('.expander').slideToggle("slow");

    });
});
```

After Animation or slidetoggle

http://jsfiddle.net/9Lw6T/123/

Is there any way to animate the divs and stop at certain height while slideup as before animation i have done it in my first try without animate.  Slidedown needs auto hide and its working with this code.

Thanks

Comment: Just a little code help here: if you declare a variable, like `var MoreDiv = $(stuff);`, use `MoreDiv` instead of `$(MoreDiv)` to access that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue when using jQuery animate going to auto so you have to do a little work around (see: [JavaScript jQuery Animate to Auto Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003220/javascript-jquery-animate-to-auto-height))

```
// get the current height
var curHeight = $textArea.height(); 
// set set the css to auto height and get how tall it is
var autoHeight = $textArea.css('height', 'auto').height(); 
// set the css back to the original height, then animate to the new height
$textArea.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 1000);
```

Here it is all together
http://jsfiddle.net/9Lw6T/127/

Comment: @ Uptown Apps
This is what exactly i need and you have solved my problem. Thanks for help and for whole code. +1

Comment: Just one question after div expanded new height is assigned to div  but how i can set height to auto after expand means no specific after expanding. Thanks

Comment: I don't think I understand what you're trying to accomplish. Can you provide a use-case?

Comment: Sorry i was mistakenly asked. I got it now that animation needs to assign some specific height to div after expanding or slide down. Thanks again for your comment.