# jQuery automatically animate div resize

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to catch a div resize not directly executed by the user?

Eg: Page has a table with 10 rows.
User delete all rows but the first. The div holding the table will "snap" to its new position (height is auto).

Is there any way to animate a div that is resizing due to its height:auto property?

Comment: Can you post a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate, please?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is very easy to do. I read an article discussing one way of attempting this here http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/animate-heightwidth-to-auto/

Or alternatively [JavaScript jQuery Animate to Auto Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003220/javascript-jquery-animate-to-auto-height)