# jquery animation not change to height auto

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have css code like this:

```
.tab_minimized {
   border-radius:20px;
   border: #0D68FF 16px solid;
   width:200px;
   height:140px;
   top: 300px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
```

And I changed value of it by jquery with this code:

```
$("#clickLaptop01").click(function() {
   $("#clickDetailTab01").removeClass( "tab_hide" );
   $("#clickDetailTab01").addClass( "tab_minimized").animate({
          height:"500px",
          width:"100%",
          top:"50px",
          borderWidth:"30px",
          borderRadius: 45
   },1500);
});
```

I need to change `height: 500px` value to `auto` but if I use `auto` there `tab_minimized` class get older `140px` height only. it was not change to height `auto`". Is there a easy way to change height `auto` in my css.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript jQuery Animate to Auto Height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003220/javascript-jquery-animate-to-auto-height). Check it :).

Comment: no friend I have checked those answers already but there is no answer I needed. I need to change this height auto to be responsive that tab_minimized class. that div must get auto value to responsive. if not some of my text are cut by bottom border

Comment: In css3 we can use !important i need to now is there a way to set height as auto. if i change height auto in using inspect element It works correctly

Comment: have you tried to use transitions or keyframes? You can't set `!important` with `animate`. I recommend you use CSS3 transitions or keyframes, it's better that `jQuery animate`. You can set a class with  the properties of `animate` and use a `transition` when change the class.

Comment: yes i tried but it not worked. I have to start width 200px width and 140px height box and need to change it to 1000px and height auto by one click. with expanding animation if u know better way to do that please let me know. i need to do the work only no matter how to do that :)

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381208/jquery-animation-not-change-to-height-auto/25382480#25382480) to use CSS3 transitions insteand of `jQuery animate`. The code change to `height: auto` with a 1.5s transition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381208/jquery-animation-not-change-to-height-auto?noredirect=1#comment39582978_25381208) you need change the `width` and `height` with a animation and the height must change to `auto`. You can do it with CSS3 `transition`:

**HTML**:

```
<div id='clickDetailTab01'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
<button id='clickLaptop01'>Show</button>
```

**CSS**:

```
#clickDetailTab01.tab_minimized {
   width: 1000px;
   height: auto;
}
#clickDetailTab01 {
    overflow:hidden;
    width: 200px;
    height: 140px;
    transition: height 1.5s, width 1.5s;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#clickLaptop01").click(function() {
       $("#clickDetailTab01").toggleClass( "tab_minimized" );
    });
});
```

You can see a jsFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/mv147eq8/. I hope help you.

Note: I only put `width` and `height` properties. You can add other properties like `border`. If you need a `transition` in these properties, you must add to the `transition` property.

Comment: Thanks Thanks It helps me...... after changing little thanks again. I cant up your reputation because I have no 10 reputation yet. when I get 10 I'll up your reputation. thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Change the animation to max-height, thus it would act as auto [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kvqn28co/)

```
$("#clickDetailTab01").addClass( "tab_minimized").animate({
      maxHeight:"2000px",
      width:"100%",
      top:"50px",
      borderWidth:"30px",
      borderRadius: 45
},1500);
```

Comment: friend but it not works I need this one for responsive that max-height not do that. height not changing when i'm re-size the browser