# Why can't I animate to 100% width in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I was trying to answer a question for someone else and I ran into weird/unexpected behavior from jquery. The width specified on rule 18 in the JSFiddle is unable to animate if I change it to 100% (in the example it is 200px by the way, so change it to 100% to see what I m talking about). I need this to be 100% so the button automatically fits the text.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfh55npj/4/)**.

The question is: "How do I make the animation work with 100% width???"

Jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ScrollDownArrow").click(function(){
        if($(".ScrollDownArrow").hasClass("Clicked")){
           $(".Hint img").fadeOut(500); 
           $(".Hint p").delay(500)/*wait on fadeout*/.animate({width: 200} /*Unfortunately width: 100% does not seem to work so I took a px value :(*/, 1000).animate({opacity:1}, 500); 
           $(".ScrollDownArrow").removeClass("Clicked");
        }else{
           $(".Hint p").animate({opacity:0.01}/*fade p out without making its width disappear for the width animation*/, 500).animate({width: 0}, 1000);
           $(".Hint img").delay(1500).fadeIn(500);
           $(".ScrollDownArrow").addClass("Clicked");
        }
    }); // End Click
});//End Ready
```

Comment: When you use 100%, are you putting the 100% in quotes?

Comment: Works fine for me. Make sure you put your percentage between quotes: `{width: '100%'}`

Comment: @Kippie Have you tried doing it on the supplied fiddle?  It doesn't work so something else is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have put a `div` element (`.Hint`) inside an `a`.

The "100%" JQuery is animating to, is the element's parent's width (i.e. the `a`'s width).

Anchor elements are, by default, inline elements (i.e. the `display` property in css is initially set to `inline`). As a consequence, the width of the anchor is `auto`.

To fix it, either set the width of the anchor to 100% or set its `display` property to `block`.

Comment: The anchor already had display: block applied. And setting the anchor width to 100% will make the button way to big. I want the button to have a width so it fits the paragraph inside (nothing more, nothing less).

Comment: @RMo So what you actually want is to [animate to `width:auto`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003220/javascript-jquery-animate-to-auto-height).

Comment: @Juhana Yes, auto might be a more appropriate value. Still doesn't work however.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a workaround myself. By saving the width when the page loads in a variable, then using this variable later to return the "p" to its original size, I can use this variable later to return the div to its original size.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfh55npj/5/)**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ButtonWidth = parseInt($(".Hint p").width());
    $(".ScrollDownArrow").click(function(){
        if($(".ScrollDownArrow").hasClass("Clicked")){
           $(".Hint img").fadeOut(500); 
           $(".Hint p").delay(500)/*wait on fadeout*/.animate({width: ButtonWidth} /*Unfortunately width: 100% does not seem to work so I took a px value :(*/, 1000).animate({opacity:1}, 500); 
           $(".ScrollDownArrow").removeClass("Clicked");
        }else{
           $(".Hint p").animate({opacity:0.01}/*fade p out without making its width disappear for the width animation*/, 500).animate({width: 0}, 1000);
           $(".Hint img").delay(1500).fadeIn(500);
           $(".ScrollDownArrow").addClass("Clicked");
        }
    }); // End Click
});//End Ready
```

This does not not explain why I can not animate to 100% / auto. That's why I am keeping this question unanswered for now.