# add animate effect to addClass/removeClass with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I am using jquery and jquery-ui and want to animate attributes on "div" tag.I want to change **height** from numeric value to "**auto**" but this effect does not work. it's properly working when i'm using a numeric value for height but it does'nt work using auto!

I've tried this so far:
See demo: [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/alihesari/nc70295d/)

Comment: No link to fiddle, place code here for better response.

Comment: @rfornal Sorry, Link was corrected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This way doesn't use `addClass`/`removeClass` but it works all the same. It uses `animate` and since you are already using the JQuery UI you'll be able to use it as is.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nc70295d/1/)

```
$("#effect1").click(function() {
    var el = $(this),
    curHeight = el.height(),
    autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
    el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 'fast');
});
```

Answer based on: [JavaScript jQuery Animate to Auto Height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003220/javascript-jquery-animate-to-auto-height)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what I see is that it is working.  Remove the effects.  To ANIMATE, you need to animate to numeric values.