# Animating height property :: HTML + CSS + JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I have noticed this 'issue' lately when trying some stuff.

Say I want to create a drop-down menu or an accordion.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper" onclick="toggle()">
  I want to be animated!
  <div class="content">
    Was I revealed in a timely fashion?
  </div>
</div>
```

Stylesheets:

```
.wrapper {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  height: auto;
  padding: 12px;
  transition: 2s height;
}

.content {
  display: none;
}

.content.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function toggle () {
  var content = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];

  var test = content.classList.contains('visible');

  test ? content.classList.remove('visible') :
  content.classList.add('visible');
}
```

I am trying to achieve a nice, smooth animation when we toggle the state of the content. Obviously this does not work. Anyone can explain to me why it does not work and how to fix it? Many thanks.

Link to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lmenus/u9q42yqu/7/).

Comment: Animating to an auto calculated height is one of those things that is much harder than it should be. Take a look at this SO post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css

Comment: you need to switch from 2 values and a transition : example http://jsfiddle.net/u9q42yqu/8/ visible/hidden - none/block are 2 states and no transition can be done. it is either seen or not :)

Comment: @GCyrillus: Thank you! However, what if I don't know the height of the content inside? As is often the case .. plus when we have to account for responsive design.

Comment: you may use javascript to retrieve height of element in order to set a max-height to each sub-division  within a loop or set a bigger value to max-height for a in-between solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first, some CSS properties CANNOT be transitioned, `display` is one of them, additionally only discrete values can be transitioned, so `height: auto` cannot as well.

In your case the problem is with `height: auto`, while there are a few [hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003220/javascript-jquery-animate-to-auto-height) for doing this, if you are just showing and hiding stuff, why not add, and use jQuery's toggle instead?

```
$(".content").toggle("slow");
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u9q42yqu/11/)

--EDIT (without jQuery)--

Because it's the `auto` that is giving us problems, we can use javascript to replace `auto` with a value in pixels and then use the css transition normally, if your content doesn't have a scroll, we can easily take that value from the `scrollHeight` property:

```
function toggle () {
  var content = document.getElementsByClassName('content')[0];

  var test = content.classList.contains('visible');
  console.log(test);

  if (test) {
    content.classList.remove('visible')
    content.style.height = "0px";
  } else {
    content.classList.add('visible');
    content.style.height = content.scrollHeight + "px";
  } 
}
```

Css

```
.wrapper {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  height: auto;
  padding: 12px;
  transition: 2s height;
}

.content {
  height: 0px;
  display: block;
  transition: 2s height;
  overflow: hidden;
} /* totally removed .content.visible */
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ddzge1p/)

Comment: Thanks, appreciated! However, jQuery cannot be considered for use in my case.

Comment: Is it just jQuery or do you not want to manipulate the height from javascript (possibly because of the inline styles)?

Comment: That edit ought to do it, I will test it tomorrow, thanks!