# Ultimate animation to height:auto with jQuery (How to retain actual height:auto)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Rephrasing this, I asked it poorly before. Hopefully this explains my goal a bit better and if anyone can help I'll be so grateful:

I have two divs set up such that when you click one, the other expands to a height appropriate for its content. The expanding div loads at `height:0;overflow:hidden` but since the animation requires an actual value instead of `height:auto`, the height is temporarily switched to 'auto', measured, stored in a variable for use in the animation, and then switched back to zero.

The problem is that the expanding div contains content that the user can choose to view or not view, and if the user views longer content, it gets cut off because the parent div has been set at that pixel value height.

So I would like the expanding div's height to be set back to 'auto' after it expands. Then if the user clicks the button again to close the div, the script will re-measure the height and change it to whatever the current pixel value is so that it can be animated back to zero.

Basically this would be the sequence of events:

1. Div #2 loads at `height:0` and this height is stored in a variable.
2. Div's height is set to auto.
3. The auto height is stored as a pixel value.
4. The height is set back to zero.
5. User clicks div #1 to open div #2.
6. Div #2's height animates from zero to the pixel height value.
7. Its height is set to 'auto' again once the animation is complete.
8. User views or hides content, which changes the height of the div.
9. User clicks div #1 to close div #2.
10. Div #2's current height is measured and stored as another pixel
    value.
11. Div #2's height is set to the new pixel value.
12. Div #2's height is animated back to zero.

Using [Box9's brilliant post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5003220/javascript-jquery-animate-to-auto-height), I've set up the following code, which successfully accomplishes steps 1 through 6. Step 7 is the important one that I can't figure out, but I'm looking for help with steps 7 through 11.

```
$(function(){
    var el = $('#ev-donate-form'),
        curHeight = el.height(),
        autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
        el.height(curHeight);
    $( "#ev-sponsors" ).click(function() {
        if(el.height() == 0)
            el.height(curHeight).animate({height: autoHeight}, 600);
        else
          el.height(autoHeight).animate({height: curHeight}, 600);
    });
});
```

I haven't gotten anything to work. I'm thinking maybe to use some kind of `setTimeout()` attached to the click function that would set the height to auto after the duration of the animation? None of my attempts at that have been successful, but I'm not very experienced with jQuery and it seems like that would work...

Here's a fiddle for experimentation: https://jsfiddle.net/q00bdngk/1/

Comment: [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) provides a `complete` callback. You could set the height to `auto` in there.

Comment: How might I do that? Could I append `.css('height','auto')` to it?

Comment: Pretty much. `el.height(val).animate({ height: val2, complete: function() { el.css('height', 'auto'); } })`

Comment: Hmm... didn't work. Here (if you view the source you'll see that the div still has inline css for the pixel height): https://jsfiddle.net/L3y9shf2/1/

Comment: Huh. Strange. Either way, you can actually just pass the function as another argument and [it will work.](https://jsfiddle.net/b9xdzysg/)

Comment: You're brilliant! Thanks! This will work for now, but if the content in the div changes length (https://jsfiddle.net/b9xdzysg/1/), do you know how I could get it to store the current height when the user clicks to close the div so that the closing animation is still smooth?

Comment: Sure. Just [save the height of the element before closing it](https://jsfiddle.net/3cuh2vo6/1/) and use that as the height next time you open it.

Comment: You're my damn hero. If you want to put it in an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: Haha glad I could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`.animate` function](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) allows you to pass a `complete` function. This function will run whenever the animation completes. At that time, you can set the height to `auto` to allow it to resize as needed.

```js
$(function() {
  var el = $('#ev-donate-form'),
    curHeight = el.height(),
    autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
  el.height(curHeight);
  $("#ev-sponsors").click(function() {
    if (el.height() == 0) {
      el.animate({
        height: autoHeight
      }, 600, function() {
        el.css('height', 'auto');
      });
    }
    else {
      el.animate({
        height: curHeight
      }, 600);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#ev-sponsors {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#ev-donate-form {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ev-sponsors">
  CLICK ME
</div>
<div id="ev-donate-form">
  <p><strong>
  Set the height of this div to 'auto' after the animation that opened it.
  </strong></p>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
    Resize this text area to change the height.
  </textarea>
</div>
```

But now you've got a problem. When you close it and re-open it, you'll see a jerk in the animation. That's because you need to update what the final height is going to be. Do that just before closing the element and you'll be good to go.

```js
$(function() {
  var el = $('#ev-donate-form'),
    curHeight = el.height(),
    autoHeight = el.css('height', 'auto').height();
  el.height(curHeight);
  $("#ev-sponsors").click(function() {
    if (el.height() == 0) {
      el.animate({
        height: autoHeight
      }, 600, function() {
        el.css('height', 'auto');
      });
    }
    else {
      autoHeight = el.height(); // Update the actual height
      el.animate({
        height: curHeight
      }, 600);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#ev-sponsors {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#ev-donate-form {
  height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ev-sponsors">
  CLICK ME
</div>
<div id="ev-donate-form">
  <p><strong>
  Set the height of this div to 'auto' after the animation that opened it.
  </strong></p>
  <textarea rows="4" cols="50">
    Resize this text area to change the height.
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I guess `.slideToggle` does this for you