# jQuery slideDown with set height and overflow

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidedown

I have the following HTML code

```
<div class="text">bla bla bla bla</div>
<div class="button">Show</div>
```

And the CSS

```
.text{
  height:100px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Assume `.text` `div` has way more text and what I do is hide the amount of text below 100px.

How can I `slideDown()` the `div` so I can view the text when I click the button?

Using `$(".button").slideDown();` doesn't work because I need to remove the height and then `slideDown()` but this will not work either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1369715/how-can-i-animate-an-element-to-its-natural-height-using-jquery

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this it is very simple and easy without creating any clone.

```
$(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){
        var $text = $(".text");
        var contentHeight = $text
                            .addClass('heightAuto').height();
        $text.removeClass('heightAuto').animate({ 
            height: (contentHeight == $text.height() ? 100 : contentHeight)
        }, 500);

    });
});
```

Added a new class

```
.heightAuto{
    height:auto;
}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QwmJP/1/)**

Comment: Interesting; I thought the 'blip' that would occur when you set `height: auto` would be much more noticeable. Is this because the CSS doesn't get rendered until the function returns (i.e. quasi-threading)?

Comment: It happens within fraction of micro seconds so.

Comment: I'm thinking it doesn't even happen. I've noticed before that I have to setTimeout() when I make css changes then try to utilize them right away. I suspect the CSS change doesn't get applied until the js method exits.

Comment: CSS doesn't get rendered until JavaScript finishes. And the size of elements isn't calculated until the size is needed or the page is rendered. When the `height: auto` is first added, the browser doesn't render it or calculate the new size. Then it calculates the size when `height()` is called. Since the `height: auto` is removed before the end of the function, the browser never gets a chance to render it that way.

Answer (score 14):

I like Shankar's solution but the functionality breaks down after the first two clicks.. This is because the auto class gets overwritten by the inline height style. So instead I altered the height attribute only.

Here's my go at it:

```
$(".button").click(function(){
    $box = $(".text");
    minimumHeight = 100;

    // get current height
    currentHeight = $box.height();

    // get height with auto applied
    autoHeight = $box.css('height', 'auto').height();

    // reset height and revert to original if current and auto are equal
    $box.css('height', currentHeight).animate({
        height: (currentHeight == autoHeight ? minimumHeight : autoHeight)
    })
});
```

One flaw is that if you add padding to the box you get some ugly jumping. Open to any solutions to fix that.

**[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rtKy3/1/)**

Improvements and suggestions are very welcome

Answer (score 4):

Clean but expensive option: Use animate directly instead of slideDown(). Determine the height you want to animate to by creating a clone and setting the height to auto.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
   var $div = $('div.text');
   $div.animate({height: determineActualHeight($div)});
});

// if you can determine the div's height without this, it would be faster
// what makes this expensive is inserting and removing an element from the dom
// of course, you aren't doing this a thousand times a second, so it's probably no biggie
function determineActualHeight($div) {
   var $clone = $div.clone().hide().css('height', 'auto').appendTo($div.parent()),
       height = $clone.height();
   $clone.remove();
   return height;
}
```

A little uglier but less expensive option: just set the height to auto, hide the element, then use slideDown() to render it:

```
$('.button').click(function() {
   $('div.text').hide().css('height', 'auto').slideDown();
}
```

Comment: beat me to it haha i made a fiddle for the second option :O (yours was a bit cleaner however) http://jsfiddle.net/GordnFreeman/thJwU/9/ :)

Comment: And that truly is the conundrum of SO is it not? Answer it thoroughly or answer it fast? Thus, I always try to upvote ALL the useful answers, and not just the first one, particularly if each contains some unique helpful detail. :)  If you did the work, you should post your answer; I'm sure it will help someone.

Comment: well i dont want to hide it... simply slideDown it or animate it

Comment: well then you want the first approach, or +ShankarSangoli's. FYI - the second option doesn't hide it, just simply makes it expand from zero instead of the current height.

Answer (score 1):

I just totally misread your question.

Unfortunately, you can't really set to auto height. But you can animate to a set height, using .animate();

`.animate({height:'200px'};`

`slideUp()'` and `.slideDown();` set the divs to `display: none` and `display: block` So you're right, that wouldn't work for what you're trying to do.

**EDIT**

I just saw Kato's post. That's probably the best option for you.

Comment: You're on the right track, your first answer was also not bad. You just need the height: auto in the css to get things rolling :)

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize the `height: auto` worked with `.slideDown();` - doesn't it default to `display: none`? Also, I wasn't aware you could do `.animate();` to `height: auto` Ha, I'm certainly no jQuery master, so I've still got a ways to go.

Answer (score 1):

**use scrollHeight property**, this can make your script dynamic.

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.text').animate({ 'height': $('.text')[0].scrollHeight }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Shankar and Erik's solutions are on the right track.  Erik fixed Shankar's problem of only working twice.  Now I'm going to fix Erik's problem of having padding:

```
$(function(){
    $(".arrow-details").click(function(e){
        var id = "#other-" + e.target.id;
        var $box = $(id);
        minimumHeight = 350;
        currentHeight = $box.outerHeight();
        autoHeight = $box.css('height', 'auto').outerHeight();
        $box.css('height', currentHeight).animate({
            height: (currentHeight == autoHeight ? minimumHeight : autoHeight)
        })
    });
})
```

Basically, I took Erik's jsfiddle and changed innerHeight to outerHeight.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/webdataintel/rtKy3/113/)

I also had several `div`s on my page where the height can change, so instead of hard coding which div gets changed, the impacted `div` is now determined by the ID of the button/image/div the user clicks on.