# Why is my `then` event firing before my `when` event is finished?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise, .when

I have a list of previewed posts on my page. When they're clicked on, they should load the full text of the post, load the comments, and slide down to reveal both.

I have one function, partialSlide, that simulates slideDown, but starting at a specified height - it's adapted from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9036261/709443). The other two functions, loadFullPost and loadComments are mine.

All the events are firing, but partialSlide is firing before loadComments is finished, so it's not taking them into account when calculating the height, and hence they're being cut off.

Why is that happening when I have them set up in a when > then format?

```
$.when(loadComments(divID,postID)).done(partialSlide(divID));
```

Am I misunderstanding how promises work in jQuery? Elsewhere in my code they've worked as expected (the `then` only runs once the `when` is done).

Full functions below:

```
function loadFullPost(permalink,divID,postID) {
    $.when($.when($.ajax({url: permalink+"?ajax=true", success:                 
       function(result){$("#"+divID+"").html(result);}})).then
           (function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
            $.when(loadComments(divID,postID)).done(partialSlide(divID));
    }));    
}

function loadComments(divID,postID) {
    $.ajax({url: "ajax-comments/?post_id=" + postID, success:      
    function(result){
        $("#" + divID + " .comment.list").html(result);
    }});
}   

function partialSlide(divID) {
    var contentHeight = $("#"+divID+"").addClass('full').height();
        $("#"+divID+"").removeClass('full').animate({ 
            height: (contentHeight == $("#"+divID+"").height() ? 100 : contentHeight)
        }, 500);    
}
```

Comment: `loadComments` doesn't return a pomise, so `$.when` has nothing to do. Also, you want to pass a function to `.done`. Right now you are calling `partialSlide` and pass its *return value* (which is `undefined`) to `.done`. `foo(bar())` and `foo(bar)` are very different.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/306t2cez/1/ - there is no need to make that complex

Comment: return the `$.ajax` from `load comments`, I hope jQuery ajax has implemented Promise.

Comment: @sabithpocker - It does, yes.

Comment: Why are you doing `$.when($.when(...))`?  What are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: The multiple $whens are a mistake, I've misunderstood their use.

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Thanks, your (much) simplified version of the functions works perfectly; do you want to add them as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already explained the comments there are multiple problems in the code like

1. `$.ajax()` returns a promise object so there is no need to pass it to `$.when()`
2. Since you want something to do after the ajax request in `loadComments` is completed, you need to return a promise from that. Since `$.ajax` returns a promise you can just return that value
3. You need to pass a function reference to `done()`, when you do `partialSlide(divID)` you are actually calling the function `partialSlide` by passing the parameter and is passing the value returned from it(`undefined` in this case) as the done callback.

So

```
function loadFullPost(permalink, divID, postID) {
    $.ajax({
        url: permalink + "?ajax=true",
        success: function (result) {
            $("#" + divID + "").html(result);
            loadComments(divID, postID).done(function () {
                partialSlide(divID)
            })
        }
    })
}

function loadComments(divID, postID) {
    return $.ajax({
        url: "ajax-comments/?post_id=" + postID,
        success: function (result) {
            $("#" + divID + " .comment.list").html(result);
        }
    });
}

function partialSlide(divID) {
    var contentHeight = $("#" + divID + "").addClass('full').height();
    $("#" + divID + "").removeClass('full').animate({
        height: (contentHeight == $("#" + divID + "").height() ? 100 : contentHeight)
    }, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I think your issue might be that loadComments doesn't have a return so the promise is never given to the when.

```
function loadComments(divID,postID) {
    return $.ajax({url: "ajax-comments/?post_id=" + postID, success:      
    function(result){
        $("#" + divID + " .comment.list").html(result);
    }});
}
```

As pointed out in the comments this line is calling partialSlide immediately since you have parentheses at the end. It should be:

```
$.when(loadComments(divID,postID)).done(function () { partialSlide(divID) });
```

Comment: what about `.done(partialSlide(divID))`? - irrespective of whether `loadComments` returns promise or not the `partialSlide` is called

Comment: That's only part of the problem.

Comment: partialSlide is just seems like its your completion function so it doesn't need to return a promise or anything really since it just animates a height. jquery ajax call returns a promise by default.

Comment: If there are no promises given to a when I believe done is called immediately.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace: `.done(partialSlide(divID))` should be `.done(function(){ partialSlide(divID); })`

Comment: @RocketHazmat that is true as well. He is calling that immediately there. Missed that.